# Firebreath Plugin Crashes

Tags: npapi, firebreath

My Firebreath Plugin Crashes in Chrome when adding Additional Include Directories or Additional Library Directories. Is this because of some directory permission issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whenever something crashes - find out [where it crashes](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Debugging+Plugins)! If that doesn't help you, you need to add at least that info and the OS when asking. As is, this is unanswerable.

Comment: .. Not only that, but the plugin can't possibly be crashing when adding those things, since those things occur not in Chrome or at runtime but in the build process.  If what you mean is that when you add additional include or library directories during build, the resulting plugin starts to crash, that becomes a more useful (but still weird and unanswerable) question.  Try debugging it and find out where the crash is, as Georg suggests